# Edit Index File in WP

Tags: css, wordpress, web, indexing, editing

I have an anomaly.  So, I'm trying to edit\remove the background in the .site-header-main of my of a site.  I edited via theme editor however, seems that such is not taking as the code is in the index file.  Here is the website: https://retrocarsales.com/

Code in theme CSS after change via style.cc and\or theme editor:

```
    .site-header-main, .site-description, .site-title-text a {
    background: none;
}
    .site-header-main {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Code in (Index):258 when inspecting:

```
    .site-header-main, .site-description, .site-title-text a {
    background: #444444!important;
    color: #ffffff!important;
}
    .site-header-main {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444444!important;
}
```

NOTE: The code above is NOT found in Domain\WP-Content\Theme\index or in Domain\index  I only find the related code in domain/wp-content/themes/theme-name/style.css in which there its good but its not executed on live site ... seems the site gets code from index not style.css

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **never direct edit the theme's file** if you are not a developer - this may be break your site or even make your site down if you make mistakes.

Instead of that, you can safely add your custom CSS by go to **Appearance** > **Customize** > **Additional CSS** (remember to add **"!important"** to overwrite current CSS rules).

See below image for more detail:
[image]

Comment: @ thống nguyễnI forgot to add the "!important" ... SOLVED!

THANK YOU KINDLY

Comment: @Gary glad to helped you!